# jquery not recognizing class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a difficult time getting a selector to work properly. I have a class name stored in a variable, which I would usually select like:

```
$("." + class_name)
```

When I do this, however, I'm getting the error: **`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .`**
as if it's not recognizing the class selector.

Almost every other example of how to select classes based on variables uses this method as well, am I missing something really basic here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the value of `class_name`

Comment: "group2"
I can run console.log( $(".group2").length ); and get the proper result.

Comment: can you post some more code?

Comment: can you log `console.log("." + class_name)` before the selector

Comment: from what I can see `class_name` has a empty string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do an `alert(class_name)` on the line immediately before this to make sure class_name actually has a value.  Also, make sure the class name is spelled properly in both the variable and in your style sheet.  Also, remember, css classes are CASE-SENSITIVE, so "myClass" <> "Myclass".  If all that checks out, try creating a variable on the line before the alert and assigning "." + class_name to it.  Something like this:

```
var fixit = "." + class_name;
$(fixit);
```

Let me know if none of this helps.

Comment: Thats what it was. The class names are being fed by an array, which somehow gets an empty string as the first one. It seems like this was the first correct answer so I will accept it in a few minutes when it lets me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a '.' in `class_name` as well, so you're trying to select `$('..class_name')`. Do `console.log(class_name)` to confirm. Either that, or `class_name` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
 var class_name = "container";
 var selector = "."+class_name;

 $(selector).html("hello universe !");
 console.log(typeof (selector)); //prints "string"
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JG9q3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think class name is not in double quotes or empty.Following code is working fine in jsFiddle

```
var className="test"
alert($("." + className).html());
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G7Gz2/)